# Timer Switch wiring that requires a neutral wire

Tags: wiring, switch, timer

[image][image]

I'm trying to replace a basic on/off switch for the fan in my powder room with a timer switch (which requires a neutral). The timer switch comes with red, white, black and green wires.

In the same box there's also an existing light switch.

Comment: I'm not sure what your ASCII art is supposed to indicate. I have no idea what the "LL", "LR" etc. are. How about pictures of the actual wiring and the pictures you took of the wiring as it was before you started (you did take those, right?). Maybe include the make/model of the timer switch and a picture of the instructions (or even better, a link to them online). By [edit]ing this info into your question it will help us help you.

Comment: The timer is Enerlites model HET06A-R-W.  The instructions basically say Red to Load, Black to Hot, White to Neutral and Green to ground (pretty standard, I think).  New to this, how do I add a photo?  Unfortunately, I did not take picture of before when the basic on/off switch was connected.

Comment: I did not mention this before, but we did previously have a working countdown timer switch (with a neutral wire) connected.  However, it died and I replaced it with a basic on/off switch (for the interim).  I have now acquired a new timer and is trying to get it to work.

Comment: Good start. How about a pic showing how the wires are connected to the switches. Maybe provide a hint about which of the 4 cables goes where. One has to be providing power to the box, the others go out _somewhere_. Which ones are you dealing with for this issue?

Comment: @Tony -- yes, can you get us a photo showing the connections to the switches please?

Comment: B=Black, W=White wires in the diagram above.  If I connect W3 to the rest of the capped white wires, then the fan runs constantly even if B1 is not connected to anything.

Comment: Can you figure out which cable brings power into the box?

Comment: If I connect W3, then the fan runs constantly.  Does that not mean that this is cable that brings power into the box?

Comment: @Tony -- connect W3 and then *stop playing with the white wires* -- they're all neutrals here, and thus all need to be connected to each other.  Once W3's hooked back up, then you can turn the breaker off and see which of B2, B3, or B4 causes *both* the fan and light to not work when disconnected; that's your neutral.  Also, do you know where B1 goes to?